# Cannot concatenate int and string in c

Tags: c

I can't  and string in  c these strings .

code

```
void main
{
    char buffer[10];
    int degrees=9;
    sprintf(buffer,"%d",degrees);
    string completeMessage=(("turnAnticlockwise(%s);",buffer));
    printf(completeMessage);
}
```

Any help would be awsome!

Comment: C doesn't have a 'string' type.  In fact, it doesn't have any sane string type at all.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please *copy* from your source, never *retype* your code here. Typos, like omitting your parens on `main()` invariably creep in.

Comment: Why not `sprintf(completeMessage, "turnAnticlockwise(%d);", degrees)`?

Comment: Unfortunately, C does not let you invent your own syntax. Whoever convinced you that `string completeMessage=(("turnAnticlockwise(%s);",buffer));` should work in C, hasn't been telling you the truth.

Comment: even better use `snprintf` and you are safe that you don't have buffer overruns. So what is your question?

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you want this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char buffer[30];  // note it's 30 now, with 10 the buffer will overflow
    int degrees=9;
    sprintf(buffer, "turnAnticlockwise(%d)",degrees);
    printf("%s", buffer);
}
```

This small program  will output :

```
turnAnticlockwise(9)
```

Answer (score 1):

see:
http://www.cesarkallas.net/arquivos/faculdade/estrutura_dados_1/complementos%20angela/string/conversao.html
Specifically  this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char str[10]; /* MUST be big enough to hold all 
                  the characters of your number!! */
  int i;

  i = sprintf(str, "%o", 15);
  printf("15 in octal is %s\n",   str);
  printf("sprintf returns: %d\n\n", i);

  i = sprintf(str, "%d", 15);
  printf("15 in decimal is %s\n", str);
  printf("sprintf returns: %d\n\n", i);

  i = sprintf(str, "%x", 15);
  printf("15 in hex is %s\n",     str);
  printf("sprintf returns: %d\n\n", i);

  i = sprintf(str, "%f", 15.05);
  printf("15.05 as a string is %s\n", str);
  printf("sprintf returns: %d\n\n", i);

  return 0;
}
```